# PHP Function only accepting array("a","b") as param and not variable that IS an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit lost here, I am trying to call a function that will only accept an array parameter like this:

this works fine:

```
test($var1, $var2, $var3, array("a", "b", "c"));
```

this does not:

```
$arr = array();
```

//add some stuff to array:

```
$arr[] = "value1";

test($var1, $var2, var3, $arr);
```

Is it me or should this work..?

the function im trying to call:

```
public function addElement($elementType, $id, $type, array $data = array())
{
    $path = $this->getPath($elementType, $id, $type);

    return $this->post($path, $data);
}
```

I checked if $arr actually has elements and it looks fine as well.

[edit]

Narrowed it down a bit, the function accepts this as a valid parameter:

```
$a = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12");
test($var1, $var2, $var3, $a);
```

But not when i create an empty array and add values to it in a loop:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = "string";
test($var1, $var2, $var3, $a);
```

This fails, content of both arrays is identical so this is not making sense..

Comment: You need to provide us a [mcve] otherwise we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: The line where you say "this works fine" would not work fine as it has a syntax error in it. Please be more explicit with your examples.

Comment: I cannot add much more code (that would be relevant) as it is pulling data from a 3rd party website which requires my login.

Comment: I don't see a [mcve] here. @Riz

Comment: I don't see a [mcve] here. @scro